# Upload images from rails to linode

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3.2, capistrano, carrierwave, linode

So I want to upload images from my running rails 3 app wich is hosted on linode, the file upload works locally, but when i try to do it remotely it fails. I've read some options, but almost all of them looks like this:

```
CarrierWave.configure do |config|

  if Rails.env.development? || Rails.env.test?
    config.storage = :file
  else
  config.storage = :fog
  config.fog_credentials = {
      :provider               => 'AWS',
      :aws_access_key_id      =>  'some_access_key_id',
      :aws_secret_access_key  => 'some_secret_key',
      :region                 => 'eu-west-1'
   }
   config.fog_directory = 'bucket_name'
   end
end
```

but when i change it to linode options it gave me the

```
ArgumentError (linode is not a recognized storage provider):
  app/controllers/users_controller.rb:50:in `create'
```

then i took the sftp option:

```
CarrierWave.configure do |config|
config.sftp_host = "my.host.com"
config.sftp_user = "username"
config.sftp_folder = "public_html/uploads"
config.sftp_url = "http://my.host.com/uploads"
config.permissions = 0666
config.directory_permissions = 0777
config.storage = :file  
config.sftp_options = {
  :password => "mypass",
  :port     => 22
}
end
```

but i still got the same error:

```
ArgumentError (linode is not a recognized storage provider):
 app/controllers/users_controller.rb:50:in `create'
```

I'm workink with aptana and rails 3.2 using git and then deploy with capistrano after every change i make and commit. I ran into a similar question here [Uploading files to Linode using CarrierWave](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15596077/uploading-files-to-linode-using-carrierwave) but it has no answer. I don't know if it can be done with carrierwave but any suggestion will be taken, any help you can give is welcome.

Thank you!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As you have 20GB of storage on your Linode instance and your server runs already on Linode, you want to chose the carrierwave option `:file` - because you just want to store the images on the filesystem of your (Linode) server, not any external storage provider like S3. (Linode is not a recognized carrierwave storage provider, hence the error message)

Try just leaving it with the same option than your development environment:

```
CarrierWave.configure do |config|
    config.storage = :file
end
```

Comment: Thanks Frank, actually that was the first thing i did when i deployed, the issue was that it was not creating any folder or saving any file anywhere (locally or in the server) :(

Comment: After a lot of changes with no good results I've took it from the beginning and I made it work under the public folder, otherwise it upload the image on the desired folder, but on the image_tag where i want to display it, it searches for the public folder, even when an absolute path provided. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

if your app is small one.. then i suggest Use Openshift to deploy your app... checkout this [deploying rails app in openshift](http://ror-tech.blogspot.in/2013/04/deploying-rails-application-on-to.html)

openshift provides one permanent data directory to store data and its free, and its really very easy to deploy there.

Comment: Thanks Pandurang, but the app is already deployed and running on the server on production environment, the issue comes the moment I want to upload a picture when creating the user.